# Can a foreign tourist buy a gun magazines in the USA?

Tags: united-states

I want to buy an empty Magpul 30 rds magazine as a souvenir.

Just magazines, not the gun. Can I buy them in California or Nevada without a licence or anything?

Comment: With ammunition, or just an empty magazine?

Comment: AakashM// Only empty magazine.

Comment: Just be sure not to bring the magazines in you carry-on luggage. They'll probably trigger the metal detector and once you open it, I suspect, BCP will not look you with good eyes...

Comment: <comments removed> Folks, please stop guessing and answering in comments. If you have a answer based in law, please post it below. Thanks.

Comment: There is an article in Washington Examiner (http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/warning-d.c.-cops-under-orders-to-arrest-tourists-with-empty-bullet-casings/article/2535216) that says "Empty shell casings are considered ammunition in Washington, D.C., so they are illegal to possess unless you are a resident and have a gun registration certificate,". Sadly I couldn't find anything speific for California or Nevada,

Comment: @gmauch A magazine isn't "empty shell casings," though.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer: No license is required in any U.S. jurisdiction to buy a firearm magazine.

There are some jurisdictions that restrict the sale of "high-capacity" magazines to civilians.  That's something that is changing often enough that any answer covering the U.S. will probably quickly be obsolete.  Suffice it to say: If you can find it in a store there are no legal restrictions or conditions on purchasing it.

Technically an "export" license *might be* required under [ITAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) to take magazines out of the country, but in practice this has not *yet* applied to individuals carrying low-tech small-arms accessories (in quantities reasonable for an individual's use).

Comment: You should probably add that possession of magazines may be illegal in transit or destination countries.

Comment: @feetwet can you cite anything in your answer?

Comment: @Andrew: Not that I can think of.  I can't prove a negative (first paragraph).  And the laws and rules both by state and lower jurisdictions are changing too fast for even industry and advocacy groups to track.  Even the ITAR regulations are being reconsidered, and there was some suggestion that individuals might be burdened in some cases but nothing concrete at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It would be impractical to regulate everything that is or could be a part of a firearm.  Imagine trying to regulate all metal pipes, for example.  So for purposes of possession, ownership, and transfer, one specific part of every firearm is legally considered the firearm.  It's always some part that is both essential to the operation of the weapon, and can't be easily improvised to make a working weapon from the other parts.  For example, on an AR15/M16 rifle, the lower receiver is considered the firearm:

[image]

All other parts of an AR15/M16 can be bought and sold by anyone without restriction, because they're harmless without the lower receiver.  (Except maybe as a club.)

I'm not aware of any type of weapon for which the magazine is considered the firearm.  A magazine is not essential to the operation of the weapon, since you can always single-load cartridges by hand.

Comment: "A magazine is not essential to the operation of the weapon..." except for guns with magazine disconnects!